# Can't use function for setTimeout() on meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, settimeout

I don't understand the different behaviour:

**first.js**

```
Template.example.onRendered(function() {
    timerId = setTimeout ( function() { console.log(Random.id()) }, 3000 );
});
```

So this will give me a random id on the console after 3 seconds - which is exactly what it should do.

**second.js**

```
function anything() {
    console.log(Random.id());
}

Template.example.onRendered(function() {
    timerId = setTimeout ( anything(), 3000 );
});
```

This gives me the random id immediatly, so there won't be any action after 3 seconds. This is not what I want, but I need to use a named function, so the first attempt is not enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling your function, instead of passing it to `setTimeout`.

Do it like this:

```
timerId = setTimeout(function() { anything(); }, 3000);  // anonymous function calling the named function
```

Or

```
timerId = setTimeout(anything, 3000);  // passing the named function without calling
```

Or

```
timerId = setTimeout(anything.bind(null), 3000); // new function with "this" pointing to null
```

What you did originally was equivalent to:

```
timerId = setTimeout(undefined, 3000); // function without return statement will "return" undefined
```